# GlanceSync information needed to synchronise images

Tags: fiware, fiware-glancesync

I am getting introduced into GlanceSync and I have a question about:

What information do I need to synchronise the images to a region? 
Do I need to know the IP and port of the glance server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the credential to upload the image, i.e. user, password,
tenant name, region name and keystone URL.

The address and port of the glance server is obtained from keystone with
the credential: each server is registered as an endpoint of the "image"
service. This is the way OpenStack works.

Take a look to the [documentation of FIWARE GlanceSync](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-glancesync#configuration) to get more details about it.